# Lose me once vs lose me twice

Tags: riddle

> Lose me once and get rich.
>
> Lose me again and get poor.
>
> What am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer is

> A tooth

Lose me once and get rich.

> In some countries when a child loses their baby teeth they get money from the tooth fairy.

Lose me again and get poor.

> Losing a tooth in the same place a second time is not good and you can be poorer (figuratively) for it.

Comment: You got it! ^ ^

Comment: Or losing a tooth a second time can mean a large dentistry bill.

Answer (score 6):

Is it

> A trick/trap?

Explanation

> If you fall for a trick once, then you become wise to it. But, if you fall for the same trick again, then you were never wise to it.

Comment: Interesting, yet not the one.

Answer (score 5):

Could it be:

> Zeroes

Reasoning:

> If all your bank accounts are 0's then you have no money, but if you lose those 0's then you must now have money and be rich :)

> If you lose all those 0's you now have on the end of your bank account balance, then you are poor again. (Ex. 100000 --> 1)

Comment: Nice answer! But that is not what I have in mind.

Comment: Wasn't sure if it was a stretch or not lol

Answer (score 3):

I thought it was

> Inhibitions

Reason

> Lose them and you can become free possibly to make your fortune.
>
> However, once if you lose them when you are rich you can quickly lose everything.